# EF Code First Configuration of shared Base Class --> Single Configuration File

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF 5.0 Code First in a C# project.  I have a base clase which the majority of my domain models derive from.

```
public abstract class AuditableModelBase
{
    public Int32 CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile CreatedByUserProfile { get; set; }

    public Int32 UpdatedByUserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile UpdatedByUserProfile { get; set; }

    public AuditableModelBase()
    {
        CreatedByUserId = 1;
        CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        UpdatedByUserId = 1;
        UpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

However, for every single entity I have to define the specific configurations to wire these relationships together.

```
// Relationships
        this.HasRequired(amb => amb.CreatedByUserProfile).WithMany().HasForeignKey(amb => amb.CreatedByUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        this.HasRequired(amb => amb.UpdatedByUserProfile).WithMany().HasForeignKey(amb => amb.UpdatedByUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I'm looking for a way to just declare one Configuration similar to the one directly above for the abstract base class instead of having to create an individual configuration file for each of my entities.  I'd love to just have one file named "AuditableModelBaseMap.cs" which will have my configuration instead of "Entity1Map.cs", "Entity2Map.cs", "Entity3Map.cs", etc. especially since all of those files have the exact same code inside.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: I know this doesn't directly address the question, but if you don't have a code base yet then auditing is really a crosscutting concern and is better addressed using AOP, not inheritance.

Comment: @BlackICE - No, Auditing is not a concern addressed in AOP, as it's not a business model concern, it's a data model concern. Auditing is typically done by triggers in the database, this code is merely defining the database entries for the triggers to use in the model.  You're confusing Inheritence in the business domain with inheritance in the data domain.  Inheritence here is merely an implementation detail used to share common auditable fields among entities.  AOP is for cross-cutting concerns that cross all (or many) layers.  Data Auditing != Security Auditing != Logging

Comment: @BlackICE - Database based auditing also audits manual changes made outside the application by someone using sql management studio or SSIS, something that using business domain logging won't catch.

Comment: @MystereMan Yes you can do auditing in the models ( code first). Just you need to modify the context before saving auditable object. After all it is Code First , no sql, not trigger

Comment: @DanHunex - of course you CAN, but doing so is seldom a good idea in my experience.  Triggers are far more efficient, and work with manual changes.  Still, it doesn't change the fact that this is about the data model, not about the problem domain.. even if you use AOP you still need a data model to record the changes to.

Comment: Agree with @DanHunex --> I override the "SaveChanges" method to accomplish this.

Comment: @KWondra I thought you didnt need that but i do undelete it for u if u need it

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below but I didnt test it  .However if I were you, I wouldnt design Audit tables this way

```
class AuditableModelBaseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AuditableModelBase>
    {
        public AuditableModelBaseMap ()
        {
            this.HasRequired(amb => amb.CreatedByUserProfile).WithMany().HasForeignKey(amb => amb.CreatedByUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            this.HasRequired(amb => amb.UpdatedByUserProfile).WithMany().HasForeignKey(amb => amb.UpdatedByUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
```

THIS IS MY WAY OF Doing AUDITING

```
        public interface IEntity
            {
                int Id { get; set; }
            }

         public interface IAuditable : IEntity
            {
                string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
                string CreatedBy { get; set; }
                DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
                DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
            }

    Now any entity which is auditable will implement this class your context will look the following




            public class MYContext : DbContext, ILicensingContext
            {
                private readonly IAuditLogBuilder _auditLogBuilder;


                public LicensingContext()
                    : this(new AuditLogBuilder())
                {
                }
                private IDbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }

                private IDbSet<AuditLog> AuditLogs { get; set; }


                public MyContext(IAuditLogBuilder auditLogBuilder)
                {
                    _auditLogBuilder = auditLogBuilder;
                }



                /// <summary>
                ///     1. Constructs the AuditLog objects from the context
                ///     2. Calls SaveChanges to save the actual object modified
                ///     3. It updates the Log objects constructed in step 1 to populate the IDs returned from the Db
                ///     4. Saves the AuditLogs
                /// </summary>
                /// <returns></returns>
                public override int SaveChanges()
                {
                    var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditable>().ToList();

                    _auditLogBuilder.UpdateAuditables(entries);
                    IEnumerable<AuditLog> auditLogEntities = _auditLogBuilder.ConstructAuditLogs(entries).ToList();


                    int countOfAffectedRecords = base.SaveChanges();

                    _auditLogBuilder.UpdateAuditLogs(auditLogEntities);
                    foreach (AuditLog auditLogEntity in auditLogEntities)
                    {
                        GetDbSet<AuditLog>().Add(auditLogEntity);
                    }
                    base.SaveChanges();
                    return countOfAffectedRecords;
                }


                public IDbSet<TEntity> GetDbSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
                {
                    return Set<TEntity>();
                }
            }

 public class AuditLogBuilder : IAuditLogBuilder
    {
        private string _username;

        private string Username
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.User != null)
                {
                    _username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                }

                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_username))
                {
                    _username = "Service Consumer";
                }
                return _username;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<AuditLog> ConstructAuditLogs(IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry<IAuditable>> auditableEntities)
        {
            var audits = new List<AuditLog>();
            if (auditableEntities != null)
            {
                audits.AddRange(auditableEntities
                                .Where(
                                     e =>
                                     e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Added ||
                                    e.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                           .SelectMany(GetAuditLogs));
            }
            return audits;
        }

        public void UpdateAuditLogs(IEnumerable<AuditLog> auditLogEntities)
        {
            foreach (AuditLog auditLog in auditLogEntities)
            {
                auditLog.RecordId = auditLog.Entity.Id;
                auditLog.UpdatedBy = auditLog.Entity.UpdatedBy;

                if (String.Equals(auditLog.PropertyName, "id", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    auditLog.NewValue = auditLog.Entity.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                }
            }
        }

        public void UpdateAuditables(IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry<IAuditable>> entries)
        {
            if (entries != null)
            {
                foreach (var entry in entries)
                {
                    entry.Entity.UpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    entry.Entity.UpdatedBy = Username;
                    if (entry.Entity.Id == 0)
                    {
                        entry.Entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        entry.Entity.CreatedBy = Username;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<AuditLog> GetAuditLogs(DbEntityEntry<IAuditable> entry)
        {
            var audits = new List<AuditLog>();

            string entityName = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entry.Entity.GetType()).Name;

            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:

                    audits.AddRange(entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Select(propertyName =>
                                                                             new AuditLog
                                                                                 {
                                                                                     EntityName = entityName,
                                                                                     CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                                                                                     NewValue =
                                                                                         entry.CurrentValues[
                                                                                             propertyName] != null
                                                                                             ? entry.CurrentValues[
                                                                                                 propertyName].ToString()
                                                                                             : String.Empty,
                                                                                     PreviousValue = String.Empty,
                                                                                     PropertyName = propertyName,
                                                                                     Entity = entry.Entity,
                                                                                     Action = Actions.Create.ToString()
                                                                                 }));
                    break;

                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    audits.AddRange(entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.Select(propertyName =>
                                                                              new AuditLog
                                                                                  {
                                                                                      EntityName = entityName,
                                                                                      CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                                                                                      NewValue = String.Empty,
                                                                                      PreviousValue =
                                                                                          entry.OriginalValues[
                                                                                              propertyName] != null
                                                                                              ? entry.OriginalValues[
                                                                                                  propertyName].ToString
                                                                                                    ()
                                                                                              : String.Empty,
                                                                                      PropertyName = propertyName,
                                                                                      Entity = entry.Entity,
                                                                                      Action = Actions.Delete.ToString()
                                                                                  }));

                    break;

                case EntityState.Modified:

                    audits.AddRange(entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.
                                          Where(
                                              propertyName =>
                                              !Equals(entry.OriginalValues[propertyName],
                                                      entry.CurrentValues[propertyName]))
                                         .Select(propertyName =>
                                                 new AuditLog
                                                     {
                                                         EntityName = entityName,
                                                         CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                                                         NewValue =
                                                             entry.CurrentValues[propertyName] != null
                                                                 ? entry.CurrentValues[propertyName].ToString()
                                                                 : String.Empty,
                                                         PreviousValue =
                                                             entry.OriginalValues[propertyName] != null
                                                                 ? entry.OriginalValues[propertyName].ToString()
                                                                 : String.Empty,
                                                         PropertyName = propertyName,
                                                         Entity = entry.Entity,
                                                         Action = Actions.Update.ToString()
                                                     }));
                    break;
            }
            return audits;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And if you were me, how would you design audit tables?  I do understand that this is "simple auditing" and not a true change tracker.

Comment: Also, this method will not work.  I had tried it.  One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'AuditableModelBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'AuditableModelBases' is based on type 'AuditableModelBase' that has no keys defined.

Comment: Yeah...yes define a key in a base like IEntity or something and do implement it in the base class

Comment: @KWondra if that helps , try it. I use it and it works as charm

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
public class AuditableModelBaseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AuditableModelBase>
{
    public AuditableModelBaseMap()
    {
        this.HasRequired(amb => amb.CreatedByUserProfile).WithMany().HasForeignKey(amb => amb.CreatedByUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        this.HasRequired(amb => amb.UpdatedByUserProfile).WithMany().HasForeignKey(amb => amb.UpdatedByUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```